# Is it be possible to migrate Google+ accounts to Google Apps for Domain?

Tags: google-workspace, google-plus

Does anybody know if it's possible to migrate a Google+ account running on a normal Google account to a Google Apps for Domain when they support it?

I'm holding out on using G+ because I don't want all this data in the wrong account.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> For those of you who’ve already started using Google+ with a personal Google Account and would prefer to use your Google Apps account, we’re building a migration tool to help you move over. With this tool, you won’t have to rebuild your circles, and people who’ve already added you to their circles will automatically be connected to your new profile. We expect this migration option to be ready in a few weeks, so if you’d like, you can go ahead and get started with your Apps account today and merge your connections once the tool is available.

From the [Official Google Enterprise Blog](http://googleenterprise.blogspot.com/2011/10/google-is-now-available-with-google.html).

***Update:***

**[The official migration tool has been released via Google Takeout](http://support.google.com/plus/bin/answer.py?hl=en&topic=2400106&answer=1716102)**.

Comment: GigaOM (among others) talked about this: http://gigaom.com/2012/07/12/google-plus-apps-account-migration-tool/