# How to move a Google+ account from a Gmail account to an apps account?

Tags: google-workspace, google-plus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will it be possible to migrate Google+ accounts to Google Apps for Domain?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18149/will-it-be-possible-to-migrate-google-accounts-to-google-apps-for-domain)

I got onto Google+ a long time ago (beta), but now that Google+ is available for apps accounts, I would like to move my profile to be associated with my Google Apps account.

Doing some searching I found instructions on how to [move circles between two accounts](http://support.google.com/plus/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1716102), but my concern is that people who have me in their circles would have to re-add my new account, and I'd want to migrate content I've published from one account to the other as well.

Is there an easy way (form / request / etc) to have my Google Plus profile detached from one Google account and added to another? (Preferably something as easy as [Google Voice's process?](http://support.google.com/voice/bin/static.py?hl=en&ts=1378507&page=ts.cs))

Comment: Ah yep. I hadn't seen that other question, or the blog post. I'll admit I am still curious if anything had yet been developed/in-beta/somehow available (as the referenced blog was from 27 October...)

Comment: @Charlie No, as of now there isn't anything yet. I'm waiting for the migration tool rather eagerly too :\

Comment: Maybe you didn't find it because they closed it, but didn't edit it to add the `google-plus` tag.

Comment: That is a distinct possibility... I also noticed that a search for google+ seems to ignore the + and without plus spelled out in the question it'd be hard to find by keyword as well. Actually this might be a meta discussion/comment if there isn't one already.

Comment: Asked on [meta](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1059/specialized-keyword-search-for-google) about searching for google+